# Comparing an int to its old value in Java

Tags: java, eclipse, for-loop, integer

I'm writing some code where I need to determine by how much an integer has changed in the last loop.

My Code:

```
import gnu.io.CommPort;
import gnu.io.CommPortIdentifier;
import gnu.io.SerialPort;
import com.leapmotion.leap.*;

import java.io.IOException;

import com.leapmotion.leap.Gesture.State;
import java.io.OutputStream;

import com.leapmotion.leap.Controller;
import com.leapmotion.leap.Frame;
import com.leapmotion.leap.Listener;
import java.lang.Math;

class SampleListenerMain extends Listener {

public void onInit(Controller controller) {
System.out.println("Initialized");
}

public void onConnect(Controller controller) {
System.out.println("Connected");
controller.enableGesture(Gesture.Type.TYPE_SWIPE);
controller.enableGesture(Gesture.Type.TYPE_CIRCLE);
controller.enableGesture(Gesture.Type.TYPE_SCREEN_TAP);
controller.enableGesture(Gesture.Type.TYPE_KEY_TAP);


}

public void onDisconnect(Controller controller) {
System.out.println("Disconnected");
}

public void onExit(Controller controller) {
System.out.println("Exited");
}
public void onFrame(Controller controller) {


Frame frame = controller.frame();

Hand hand = frame.hands().rightmost();
float positionx = hand.palmPosition().getX();
System.out.println("X: " + positionx);

float positiony = hand.palmPosition().getY();
System.out.println("Y:" + positiony);

float positionz = hand.palmPosition().getZ();
System.out.println("Z: " + positionz);

System.out.println("Hands: " + frame.hands().count());

int in_min = -117;
int in_max = 117;
int out_min = 900;
int out_max = 1900;
int in_min2 = -73;
int in_max2 = 73;

int positionmapx = (int) ((positionx - in_min) * (out_max - out_min) /     (in_max - in_min)) + out_min;
int positionmapy = (int) ((positiony - in_min) * (out_max - out_min) / (in_max - in_min)) + out_min;
int positionmapz = (int) ((positionz - in_min) * (out_max - out_min) / (in_max2 - in_min)) + out_min;


if (frame.hands().count() == 0) {
    LeapDrone.writeToArduino("0");
}


int posmapxold = 0;
int posmapyold = 0;
int posmapzold = 0;


String data = Integer.toString(positionmapy)+":"+     Integer.toString(positionmapx)+":"+Integer.toString(positionmapz);

System.out.println("data: " + data);


System.out.println("Old X: " + posmapxold);

System.out.println("Difference X: " + Math.abs(positionmapy - posmapyold));

if (Math.abs(positionmapx - posmapxold) >= 25) {


    LeapDrone.writeToArduino(data);

    try {
        Thread.sleep(50);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

if (Math.abs(positionmapy - posmapyold) >= 25) {


    LeapDrone.writeToArduino(data);

    try {
        Thread.sleep(50);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

if (Math.abs(positionmapz - posmapzold) >= 25) {


    LeapDrone.writeToArduino(data);

    try {
        Thread.sleep(50);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

posmapxold = positionmapx;
posmapyold = positionmapy;
posmapzold = positionmapz;

System.out.println("New-Old X: " + posmapxold);

try {
    Thread.sleep(100);
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}

GestureList gestures = frame.gestures();
for (int i = 0; i < gestures.count(); i++) {
    Gesture gesture = gestures.get(i);



}
}
}

   class LeapDrone {
static OutputStream out = null;

public static void main(String[] args) {
//Connect to Arduino BT

try
{
(new LeapDrone()).connect("/dev/cu.usbmodem1421");
}
   catch ( Exception e )
{
    e.printStackTrace();
System.exit(0);
}

// Create a sample listener and controller
SampleListenerMain listener = new SampleListenerMain();
Controller controller = new Controller();

// Have the sample listener receive events from the controller
controller.addListener(listener);
// Keep this process running until Enter is pressed
System.out.println("Press Enter to quit...");
try {
System.in.read();
} catch (IOException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}

// Remove the sample listener when done
controller.removeListener(listener);
}

void connect ( String portName ) throws Exception {

CommPortIdentifier portIdentifier =     CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifier(portName);
if ( portIdentifier.isCurrentlyOwned() )
{
System.out.println("Error: Port is currently in use");
}
else
{
CommPort commPort = portIdentifier.open(this.getClass().getName(),2000);

if ( commPort instanceof SerialPort )
{
SerialPort serialPort = (SerialPort) commPort;
serialPort.setSerialPortParams(9600,SerialPort.DATABITS_8,SerialPort.STOPBITS_1,
SerialPort.PARITY_NONE);
out = serialPort.getOutputStream();
}
else
{
System.out.println("Error: Only serial ports are handled by this example.");
}
}
}

public static void writeToArduino(String data)
{
String tmpStr = data;
byte bytes[] = tmpStr.getBytes();
try {
out.write(bytes);
} catch (IOException e) { }
}
}
```

For example, I have integer i. I want to run a loop and see how much i has changed by (In my case, i is assigned to an x-coord that changes every loop). I set integer j equal to i once i has been set in that loop. I then need to compare i to j.

The issue is that I have to define j as equal to something to initialize it. That means that if, for example, I initialize j by setting it equal to 0, it resets to 0 every time my code loops, which means that I can't compare i to its old value (which is supposed to be j)......

I tried using a 'for' statement, but I get errors because later in my code when I compare i and j it says that j hasn't been initialized.... I suppose because code in the for loop doesn't necessarily get run in the beginning of the program?

Sorry for the confusing question.... It's hard for me to explain!

Any help is much appreciated!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not be using a local variable if you want to access it when it loops around again. If the variable is not local, there is no need to initialise it.

For example, before the loop you have the `int j = 0`, then, each loop iteration will not reset it.

Ex:

```
int j = 0;
for(int i=0; i<someVariable; i++){
    //do code

    //compare i to j
}
```

Comment: I tried putting that in the 'init' function of the code, however, it still gives errors...

Comment: Don't set it in the init function, just set it in the actual class start.

Comment: `class SampleListenerMain extends Listener {
int j  0;
public void onInit(Controller controller) {...`

Comment: Thank you. It seems I was just being stupid..... I just put 'public int j = 0;' before the loop. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It's difficult to provide an answer without some example code to look at, but you should be able to initialize your previous value to the initial value outside the loop.

For example:

```
// Initialize our previous value to be the current value right off the bat
previousValue = currentValue;

for (int index = 0; index < whatever; index++) {

   // Do something that changes the value
   currentValue = someNewValue();

   // Calculate our delta
   delta = currentValue - previousValue;

   // Set our previous value to the new current value
   previousValue = currentValue;

}
```

If the currentValue can only be calculated in the loop for some reason, then you can add a special case for the first iteration either by using an Object type `Integer` instead of primitive `int` type for the previous value with a null value to signify its first iteration, or with a boolean flag, like so:

```
boolean firstIteration = true;

for (int index = 0; index < whatever; index++) {

   currentValue = someNewValue();

   if (firstIteration) {

      // Our first iteration has a zero delta
      delta = 0;
      firstIteration = false;

   } else {

      // Subsequent iterations compare the previous value
      delta = currentValue - previousValue;

   }

   previousValue = currentValue;

}
```